# `find <dir> type -f` Equivalent for Swift-Cocoa?

Tags: swift, cocoa, macos-sierra

I am currently porting a C++ command line tool I made over to the Cocoa-Application format as to make it more convenient and bundle it with several other utilities and applets I have made recently. The tool in question needs to search a particular directory and all of it's subdirectories so that it can create a list of existing files to reference for the remainder of it's execution.

In C++ I was able to do this easily by calling a bash script that ran the commands: `files=$(find <dir> type -f); echo "$files" > ./<reference file>`. Now I am wondering if there is any equivalent to that command so that I can do the same thing in swift, saving the file in the bundle, or running the script from the "Resources" directory so that I don't have to convolute things by installing a binary to a set location, and then using Swift to call that binary to call the script.
It would also work just as well to be able to run that command directly from inside Swift with a system call if at all possible.

BTW I am using Swift 3.0 on XCode 8.0 if it is relevant. Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to get this to SO - code level questions are best there. If that migration gets rejected, please flag and we can see if this can be changed more to scripting based as opposed to code based.

Comment: @bmike With the exception of it's talk of C++ I don't see how this is more relevant to StackOverflow than AskDifferent seeing as it is both about a language exclusive to Apple systems but also about a language which, while it can be compiled, can also be run directly as script.

Comment: Let's see how it goes here. It will need some edits on Ask Different to remain open there. It might need same here as well. I'll make sure a mod here has a look and can guide us both.

Comment: Very well, thanks for the effort. I've been looking for quite a while, including at Apple's documentation and everything seems unclear as to the proper syntax to actually perform an enumeration. Its been quite frustrating, so anything that might move me closer to my goal is appreciated.

Comment: It is an SO question as it is about how to call a shell script and where to put the script.

Comment: This is on topic for SO; you are writing code.

Answer (score 1):

The way to run subprocesses in Swift is the class [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/process) and the shell script can be in resources in the bindle and use NSBundle to find its path.

However better to rewrite that command in Swift using [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsfilemanager) to fgo through the file system

Comment: I am very new to Swift, and the only Cocoa experience I have is with much older versions of OS X (~10.5) so I would highly appreciate detail as to how to do either of those things when a button click occurs. Also, if it would require any substantially more code than performing the same action in bash I would much prefer to simply call the bash script from inside Swift.

Comment: That is two different questions - button click is similar to OSX 10.5 and do in Obj C / Swift. Writing the scrpt bit is not much code

Comment: Well if that is the case I am apparently going about it in the completely wrong way because even Apple's XCode documentation examples are rife with errors and refuse to run if I drag and drop them into an XCode Playground (of course replacing placeholders with test variables). So I'm afraid that simply doesn't help me. I can very easily map button clicks to NSView related actions, however I need a button click to begin an enumeration of all subdirectories and files in them, and every example I've found on how to do that involves several blocks of code and almost never works yet still.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this:

```
import Foundation

for arg in CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst() {
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    let en=fileManager.enumerator(atPath: arg)
    while let fileName = en?.nextObject() as? String {
//      if fileName.hasSuffix("txt") {  // if you want to test for file extension
            print(arg+"/"+fileName)
    //  }
    }
}
```